# Nodemon crashes in the middle of the process without showing any error message, how do i resolve it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, nodemon

I am running a script that is getting the files from Google drive and putting it in the s3.
Now when i run the script, the process goes smoothly for sometime then app suddenly  crashes without any error message, the script takes input also so couldn't find a way to use `nohup`

The code is like this

```js
"use strict";
const fs = require("fs");
const readline = require("readline");
const { google } = require("googleapis");
const { upload_to_s3, emptyFolder, s3_exist } = require("./helper");
const prompt = require("prompt");

const SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"];
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = "token.json";

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile("credentials.json", (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log("Error loading client secret file:", err);
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Drive API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listFiles);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const { client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris } = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    client_id,
    client_secret,
    redirect_uris[0]
  );

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: "offline",
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log("Authorize this app by visiting this url:", authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question("Enter the code from that page here: ", (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error("Error retrieving access token", err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log("Token stored to", TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Lists the names and IDs of up to 10 files.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
async function listFiles(auth) {
  let page_size;
  let page_token;
  prompt.start();

  try {
    prompt.get(
      ["stage [d (dev),s (staging),p (prod)]", "pageSize", "pageToken"],
      function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
          return onErr(err);
        }
        let stage;
        let count = 0;
        let total;
        if (
          result["stage [d (dev),s (staging),p (prod)]"] === "d" ||
          result["stage [d (dev),s (staging),p (prod)]"] === "dev"
        ) {
          stage = "dev";
        } else if (
          result["stage [d (dev),s (staging),p (prod)]"] === "s" ||
          result["stage [d (dev),s (staging),p (prod)]"] === "staging"
        ) {
          stage = "staging";
        } else if (
          result["stage [d (dev),s (staging),p (prod)]"] === "p" ||
          result["stage [d (dev),s (staging),p (prod)]"] === "prod"
        ) {
          stage = "prod";
        } else {
          console.log(
            "invalid input, default is chosen",
            result["stage [d (dev),s (staging),p (prod)]"]
          );
          stage = "dev";
        }
        // await emptyFolder("/tmp");
        console.log("Getting the files");
        console.log("  stage: " + stage);
        page_size = result.pageSize || 1000;
        console.log("  pageSize: " + page_size);
        page_token = String(result.pageToken) || null;
        console.log("  pageToken: " + page_token);
        const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });
        drive.files.list(
          {
            includeItemsFromAllDrives: true,
            supportsAllDrives: true,
            pageSize: page_size,
            pageToken: page_token,
            fields: "nextPageToken,files(id,mimeType, name,fileExtension)",
            includeRemoved: false,
          },
          async (err, res) => {
            if (err) return console.log("The API returned an error: " + err);
            const files = res.data.files;
            // console.log(res.data);
            // console.log(files);
            if (res.data.nextPageToken) {
              console.log("nextPageToken :", res.data.nextPageToken, "\n");
            }
            let promises = [];
            if (files.length) {
              const filesWithExt = files.filter((file) => {
                if (file.fileExtension) {
                  return file;
                }
              });
              total = filesWithExt.length;
              console.log("Total files", files.length);
              console.log("Total files to be moved", filesWithExt.length);
              console.log("Files:");
              // let t = 1;
              // files.map((file) => {
              //   console.log(`${file.name} - (${file.id}) [${file.mimeType}]`);
              //   // console.log(t);
              //   // t = t + 1;
              // });
              for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                const file = files[i];

                const tmpName = file.name;
                const filePath = `/tmp/${tmpName}`;
                let path = tmpName;
                if (file.fileExtension) {
                  const exist = await s3_exist(`migration-temp-${stage}`, path);
                  if (exist) {
                    console.log(path, " already exists in s3, skipped", exist);
                  } else {
                    promises.push(
                      await downloadFile(stage, file.id, path, auth)
                    );
                  }

                  count = count + 1;
                  console.log("..... ", total - count, " remaining");
                }
              }
              await Promise.all(promises).then(async (result) => {
                console.log(result);
                if (res.data.nextPageToken) {
                  console.log("nextPageToken :", res.data.nextPageToken, "\n");
                }

                // await emptyFolder("/tmp");
                process.exit(0);
              });
            } else {
              console.log("No files found.");
            }
          }
        );
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error :", err);
  }
  // prompt.stop();

  function onErr(err) {
    console.log(err);
    return 1;
  }
}

const downloadFile = async (stage, fileId, finalName, auth) => {
  const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });
  console.log(`Downloading ${finalName}`);
  return drive.files
    .get({ fileId, alt: "media" }, { responseType: "arraybuffer" })
    .then(async (res) => {
      try {
        console.log("Done downloading file.");
        // console.log(res.data);
        // var buffer = new Buffer(res.data, "binary");
        var arrBuffer = res.data;
        var buffer = Buffer.from(new Uint8Array(arrBuffer));
        // console.log("Buffer----", buffer);
        const promise_s3 = await upload_to_s3(
          buffer,
          finalName,
          `migration-temp-${stage}`
        );
        return await promise_s3;
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error while uploading", err);
      }
    });
};
```

need help resolving the crash,
the error - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
the crash looks like this
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGQvb.png)

Edit 1 : forgot to mention that i am running it on a t2.large ec2 instance, which has 50GB storage and 8GB RAM

Comment: Does it show any of your `console.logs`? if not you can also use `try / catch` to find out what might be wrong...

Comment: How big and how many? What's would be the memory footprint for every single file that you download combined? This is the memory consumption you are using. Could be the issue.

Comment: @LibbyLebyane logs are the ones i log, as you can see in the image the remaining files count and all the download affirmations, and yeah i have used try/catch.

Comment: @RandyCasburn each files can be 1MB- 90MB, i am downloading only two types of file, images and audio file, images will be 1-2MB and audios 30-80MB, the ec2 instance i am running this on has 50GB SSD storage and 8GB RAM, a t2.large instance.

Comment: Although you're putting these (files) objects into memory 2 times (`res.data`, `buffer`), I'm not thinking this is a memory issue - and certainly not with S3 - it would be with Node which maxes out at 1GB on 64bit systems. So 10-15 files might create an overflow - but, that produces a memory related error. Unless, that is, that the S3 instance is swallowing the error. You'll need to look at the server logs to see if they are reporting some error (perhaps a consumption issue, leak, etc).

Comment: @roshan poojary I was asking if your logs do appear while running the code? if they do, finding where they end could clue you where the issue is

Comment: @LibbyLebyane it always stops after downloading a file or before uploading it to s3